# How to reference a property of the view from the data template

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My `ListView` has the custom `View`:

```
public class TileView : ViewBase
{
   public DataTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; } 
   public ImageSource IconSource { get; set; } = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/umf.png", UriKind.Relative));

   protected override object DefaultStyleKey => new ComponentResourceKey(GetType(), "TileView");
   protected override object ItemContainerDefaultStyleKey => new ComponentResourceKey(GetType(), "TileViewItem");
}
```

which use the next `DataTemplate`:

```
    <local:TileView>
        <local:TileView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image 
                        Source="{Binding IconSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TileView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:TileView>
```

I want to show a single image for all items, so I was created a property in `View` class:

```
public ImageSource IconSource { get; set; } = 
  new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/umf.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

and try to reference it from a template:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding IconSource, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

but obtain the error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'IconSource' property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IconSource;
>   DataItem='ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target element is 'Image'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

When I try to write

```
Source="{Binding IconSource, 
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:TileView}}}"
```

I get

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='ClientWPF.Controls.TileView', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=IconSource; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

Sure, I can intent an image into data model, but I don't like this way by obvious reasons.

So how can I reference `ItemSource` property of the `View` from my template? Thanks.

Comment: A view doesn't have an `ItemTemplate`. It applies a `ControlTemplate` to the `ListView`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `ItemTemplate` is the property of `TileView` class. Sorry, I omitted this line by mistake.

Comment: I was started with an example from "Pro WPF in C# 2008" book by Matthew MacDonald and try to adapt it for my purposes. There are definite styles in `Generic.xaml` defined and some custom views were added. For applying the view I just write `ListView.View = (ViewBase)FindResource("ImageView");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view doesn't have an `ItemTemplate`. It applies a `ControlTemplate` to the `ListView`. Inside this one, you could to a property of view like this:

```
{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.IconSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

That's what the `ControlTemplate` of the built-in `GridView` does.

Inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView` itself, you could bind to a property of the `View` like this:

```
{Binding View.IconSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}
```